# How is JavaScript insecure, and what are the main methods used to deal with that?

Tags: javascript, security

I just read about Caja, which is a "sanitized" version of JavaScript. But I'm wondering - what is the big problem with JavaScript(it seems so widely used )? Just how dangerous is it?

Comment: It appears to me the main difference here (security wise) is it does not give direct exposure to the DOM. Which will (in theory I suppose) negate silly errors introduced by some developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes it makes vs. regular javascript are pretty well described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caja_project).

From that reference:

> Caja takes JavaScript (technically, ECMAScript 5 strict mode code),
>   HTML, and CSS input and rewrites it into a safe subset of HTML and
>   CSS, plus a single JavaScript function with no free variables. That
>   means the only way such a function can modify an object is if it is
>   given a reference to the object by the host page. Instead of giving
>   direct references to DOM objects, the host page typically gives
>   references to wrappers that sanitize HTML, proxy URLs, and prevent
>   redirecting the page; this allows Caja to prevent certain phishing
>   attacks, prevent cross-site scripting attacks, and prevent downloading
>   malware. Also, since all rewritten programs run in the same frame, the
>   host page can allow one program to export an object reference to
>   another program; then inter-frame communication is simply method
>   invocation.

And, [Google's site](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) on Caja.